# Tablesorter not initializing after Ajax replaces HTML

Tags: jquery, ajax, tablesorter

I'm using Mottie's Tablesorter jQuery addon:
https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/

I'm using the pager plugin with server-side processing, and I'm building the HTML on the server and sending it back with the JSON result for the pager plugin's ajaxProcessing function.

My table HTML gets loaded correctly, but Tablesorter doesn't do its magic (adding the colgroup for nicely-spaced columns, and updating the THEAD to make the columns sortable and to enable the filter dropdowns I added with my HTML.)

Here's a snip of the HTML I start with:

```
<table class="tableMain" id="scenarioTable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="tableRowHeader">
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="loadingCircle"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

(The "loadingCircle" class is just a CSS placeholder animation; "tableMain" and "tableRowHeader" are style classes defined elsewhere.)

Here's my Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $("#scenarioTable").tablesorter({
        cancelSelection: true,
        debug: true,
        emptyTo: "zero",
        serverSideSorting: true,
        showProcessing: true,
        sortReset: true,
        theme: "custom",
        widthFixed: true,
        widgets: ["filter", "zebra"],
        widgetOptions:
            {
                filter_childRows: false,
                filter_columnFilters: true,
                filter_formatter: null,
                filter_hideFilters: false,
                filter_reset: '.clearFilters',
                filter_serversideFiltering: true
            }
    })
    .tablesorterPager({
        container: $(".scenarioPager"),
        ajaxObject: {
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { scenarioID: 1000 },
            success : function(){ $("#scenarioTable").trigger("update"); }
        },
        ajaxProcessing: function(result, table, xhr){
            if (result && result.hasOwnProperty('mScenarioTableHTML')) {
                var toReturn = {
                    total : result["mTotalRows"],
                    filteredRows : result["mTotalFilteredRows"]
                }
                $(table).html(result["mScenarioTableHTML"]);
                return toReturn;
            }
        },
        ajaxUrl: "my URL goes here",
        page: 0,
        pageReset: 0,
        processAjaxOnInit: true,
        size: 1000,
    });
});
```

So when the page loads, Tablesorter updates the table HTML to this, as expected:

```
<table class="tableMain tablesorter tablesorter-custom tablesorter749b92e50ae53 hasFilters tablesorter-processing" id="scenarioTable" role="grid" aria-describedby="scenarioTable_pager_info">
    <colgroup class="tablesorter-colgroup"><col style="width: 100%;"></colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr class="tableRowHeader" role="row">
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all"></tbody>
</table>
```

Then my ajaxProcessing function replaces the COLGROUP, THEAD, and TBODY tags with the HTML I send from the server, and the HTML ends up looking like this:

```
<table class="tableMain tablesorter tablesorter-custom tablesorter792090cf9b53c hasFilters" id="scenarioTable" role="grid" aria-describedby="scenarioTable_pager_info">
    <thead>
        <tr class="tableRowHeader">
            <th class="filter-select">
                Trial #
            </th>
            <th class="filter-select">
                Time (sec)
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="trial" id="trial">
                  <option value="" selected="selected"> </option>
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="time" id="time">
                  <option value="" selected="selected"> </option>
                  <option value="10.5">10.5</option>
                  <option value="13.4">13.4</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td id="101" class="notFlagged">
                1
            </td>
            <td id="102" class="flagged">
                13.4
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td id="103" class="notFlagged">
                2
            </td>
            <td id="104" class="notFlagged">
                10.5
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So Tablesorter only adds the "odd" and "even" classes to the TR tags for zebra striping, and nothing else.  The rest of the HTML is exactly what I send from the server.

Is there a way to have Tablesorter update the HTML I load, or does Tablesorter have to build the HTML itself in order to add in the sorting and filtering stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pager `ajaxProcessing` function should not replace the entire table. If you want to update the header, it is better to include the same number of columns (look at the HTML of [this demo](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-pager-ajax.html#html)). Instead return a `headers` value from the `ajaxProcessing` function as described in [the documentation](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#array_rows_as_jquery_object) for returning a object.

If you *must* update the entire table, don't use the `ajaxProcessing` function. Instead bind to the pager events, then:

- Detroy the current tablesorter instance, and reinitialize it after the pager completes.
- Or, use [`updateAll`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#updateall) to update tablesorter's `thead` and `tbody` content. This isn't recommended because it is still problematic and may lead to a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks Mottie!  So, if ajaxProcessing just returns a "rows" and "headers" value, is there a way to add an ID and a class to each table cell?  I need to allow the user to click a table cell and then run some code based on which cell was clicked.  I therefore want to specify the class for each table cell, which I'll use to show the cell's current status, and I need to store a piece of data for each clickable cell to use in the code when the cell is clicked.

Comment: Without seeing the code, I would say use a delegated event binding and then on click, check the cell's `rowIndex` and `cellIndex` parameters to determine the position in the table (assuming there are no `rowspan` or `colspan`s in the table).